# Installing Citra Nintendo 3DS Emulator

Tags: software-installation, compiling, git

I'm installing Citra Nintendo 3DS Emulator by following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/citra-emu/citra/wiki/Building-For-Linux) and everything is running smoothly, and then I hit `git clone --recursive https://github.com/citra-emu/citra`
At first I thought everything seemed normal, but then my computer showed this message: `git is not a command...`. Now what do I do because nobody else has to go through this, they just say "Hey Linux, run `git clone --recursive https://github.com/citra-emu/citra`" and it works?

Comment: Going through situations like this when compiling is not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

git is not installed in Ubuntu by default, so install git if it isn't installed already. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install git  
cd ~/Downloads      
git clone --recursive https://github.com/citra-emu/citra
```

The third command will create a new folder named *citra* in your Downloads directory which has 95.3MB of files in it. It will take a while to download, so wait until the download is completed and the terminal returns to the terminal prompt.

Then change directories to `~/Downloads/citra` and try to install Citra again. Building Citra in debug mode using the gcc >= version 5 is recommended. The default gcc in Ubuntu 18.04 is gcc version 7.3.0.